# Excel VBA to convert all Word files in a specific folder to PDF

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, ms-word, type-conversion

I've found in below link an Excel vba that converts excel files in a specific directory to pdfs.
I want your help to do the needful changes on this code to make it converts Word documents in a specific directory to pdfs.

credits to:
https://www.listendata.com/2013/02/excel-macro-convert-multiple-excel.html

Code is shown below:

```
Sub ExcelToPDF2()
Dim Path As String, FilesInPath As String _
, OutputPath As String, OutputPath2 As String
Dim MyFiles() As String, Fnum As Long
Dim Buk As Workbook, BukName As String
Dim CalcMode As Long
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim StartTime As Date, EndTime As Date
Dim LPosition As Integer

'Specify the path of a folder where all the excel files are stored

StartTime = Timer
Path = Range("G6").Text & "\"
OutputPath = Range("G8").Text & "\"


FilesInPath = Dir(Path & "*.xl*")
If FilesInPath = "" Then
MsgBox "No files found"
Exit Sub
End If

Fnum = 0
Do While FilesInPath <> ""
Fnum = Fnum + 1
ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To Fnum)
MyFiles(Fnum) = FilesInPath
FilesInPath = Dir()
Loop

With Application
CalcMode = .Calculation
.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
.ScreenUpdating = False
.EnableEvents = False
End With

If Fnum > 0 Then
For Fnum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
Set Buk = Nothing
On Error Resume Next
Set Buk = Workbooks.Open(Path & MyFiles(Fnum))
On Error GoTo 0

If Not Buk Is Nothing Then


LPosition = InStr(1, Buk.Name, ".") - 1
BukName = Left(Buk.Name, LPosition)
Buk.Activate

OutputPath2 = OutputPath & BukName & ".pdf"

On Error Resume Next
ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=OutputPath2, 
_
Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

    On Error GoTo 0

End If

Buk.Close SaveChanges:=False

Next Fnum
End If


With Application
.ScreenUpdating = True
.EnableEvents = True
.Calculation = CalcMode
End With

EndTime = Timer
MsgBox "Task succesfully completed in " & Format(EndTime - StartTime, 
"0.00") & " seconds"

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I'd recommend having a read of the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. More specifically, you're not likely to get much help if you just ask for code without showing what you've tried, and what *specific* problems you've encountered.

Comment: Hi @Matt, appreciate your notice, but I think the question is fair enough specific. you're kindly requested to  re-evaluate the question and provide support if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found the correct VBA I was looking for:

```
'In your VBA window go to tools then references and add a reference to 
'Microsoft Word

Sub Converter()
  Dim cnt As Integer, currfile As String
  Dim TrimFile As String, Path As String, FilesInPath As String _
, MyFiles() As String, Fnum As Long
  Dim CalcMode As Long, LPosition As Long
  Dim StartTime As Date, EndTime As Date

  Dim objWord As Word.Application
  Dim objDoc As Word.Document


  ThisWorkbook.Activate
  currfile = ActiveWorkbook.Name

  Windows(currfile).Activate
  Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

  StartTime = Timer
  Path = Range("C3").Text & "\"

  FilesInPath = Dir(Path & "*.doc*")
  If FilesInPath = "" Then
    MsgBox "No files found"
    Exit Sub
  End If

  Fnum = 0
  Do While FilesInPath <> ""
    Fnum = Fnum + 1
    ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To Fnum)
    MyFiles(Fnum) = FilesInPath
    FilesInPath = Dir()
  Loop

  With Application
    CalcMode = .Calculation
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
  End With

  If Fnum > 0 Then
    For Fnum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
      Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
      'objWord.Visible = True

      On Error Resume Next

      Set objDoc = Word.Documents.Open(Path & MyFiles(Fnum))

      On Error GoTo 0

      If Not objDoc Is Nothing Then

        LPosition = InStr(1, objDoc.Name, ".") - 1
        TrimFile = Left(objDoc.Name, LPosition)

        On Error Resume Next

        objDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=objDoc.Path & "\" & TrimFile & ".pdf", 
        ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, _
        OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:= _
wdExportAllDocument, From:=1, To:=1, Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, _
IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, CreateBookmarks:= _
wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, BitmapMissingFonts:= _
True, UseISO19005_1:=False



      End If

      objDoc.Close

   Next Fnum
  End If


  With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = CalcMode
  End With

  objWord.Quit

  Set objDoc = Nothing
  Set objWord = Nothing

  EndTime = Timer
  MsgBox " Task succesfully completed in " & Format(EndTime - StartTime, "0.00") & " 
seconds"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, the easiest way I can think of to do this is to just record a macro. If you go to Word->Developer->Record a Macro, you can record the function that you want to do. From there, you would have the code, and you can change certain areas from there. Here is the code I got with a few tweaks to do what I think you are looking for:

```
   Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
'
    Dim i As Integer, FileLocation As String, WDoc() As Word.Document

    Dim FilesInPath As String, Path As String, MyFiles() As String, iend As Integer
    Path = "C:\...\" ' This is where you would like to get the files that need to be exported to .pdfs
    NewPath = "C:\...\" ' This is where you would like to send the exported files
    FilesInPath = Dir(Path & "*.doc*")
    iend = 0
    Do While FilesInPath <> ""
        iend = iend + 1
        ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To iend)
        MyFiles(iend) = FilesInPath
        FilesInPath = Dir()
    Loop

    For i = 1 To iend
        ReDim Preserve WDoc(i)
        Set WDoc(i) = Word.Documents.Open(Path & MyFiles(i))
        FileLocation = NewPath & WDoc(i).Name & ".pdf" ' Location and name of new file
        WDoc(i).ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=FileLocation, ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, _
            OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:= _
            wdExportAllDocument, From:=1, To:=1, Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, _
            IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, CreateBookmarks:= _
            wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, BitmapMissingFonts:= _
            True, UseISO19005_1:=False
        WDoc(i).Close
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @Parker.R, Thanks for your help. I've tried my best but I could't suit above code to my required output since I have a little experience in coding. would you please edit it in away that it can convert all word files to pdf?, I would highly appreciate your effort.

Comment: Hey @Ready2go, I edited the code above. You will need to change where you would like to import the files and where you would like to export it. If it works, click the check mark on the side for me. It worked for me when I did it from Microsoft Word VBA.

Comment: Hey @Parker.R, It works fine with me on Word, is there any way to make it works on Excel. Actually, I have a project on Excel and it is a part of that project.